# Нужно тире или не нужно?

Tags: тире

> Наша команда, имя **которой (—) «Взъерошенные Тигрольвы»**, пришла к вам совместно с целью, чтоб провести для вас урок, посвящённый орфографии русского языка

Comment: Это — не кончится никогда. Это навсегда, как вирус гриппа. Для лечения срочно нужны тексты классиков — Пушкин, Достоевский, Толстой и т.д.

Comment: Предложение, состоящее из стилистических  и пунктуационных ошибок, нежелательно использовать для изучения орфографии.

Comment: Зачем первая запятая?..

Comment: В первой части перечислении слов и словосочетаний)  Тире тоже обозначает незаконную паузу. Сравнить:  Имя команды – Тигровые Кошки. Это в простом предложении, а в сложном предложении полноценную паузу не сделаешь.

Comment: А заголовок кто исправлять будет?

Comment: Я думаю, тире нужно, поскольку отсутствует связка. В справочнике Розенталя про этот случай не написано, значит, ставим тире.